# Julia - Worker can't find function

Tags: multithreading, julia

I'm currently using the Atom editor to work with Julia 0.5 and somehow fail to make functions available to my worker threads. Here is my testfile test.jl:

```
module testie
export t1
  function t1()
    a= rand()
    println("a is $a, thread $(myid())")
    return a
  end
end

if nprocs()<2
  addprocs(1)
end
@everywhere println("Hi")
using testie
t1()
println(remotecall_fetch(t1,2))
```

Executing this file, I get as output a "Hi" from the master and the worker, and the master will also output the "a is ..." line. But the worker won't, and on the remotecall_fetch line it throws the following error msg (shortened)

```
LoadError: On worker 2:
UndefVarError: testie not defined
```

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/parallel-computing/ states: *using DummyModule causes the module to be loaded on all processes; however, the module is brought into scope only on the one executing the statement.* Nothing more I could see how to solve this situation. I tried to add an @everywhere before the using line, also tried to add an `@everywhere include("test.jl")` right before it. Didn't help. This should be really simple but I can't figure it out.

On SO I only found [Julia parallel programming - Making existing function available to all workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730507/julia-parallel-programming-making-existing-function-available-to-all-workers) but this doesn't really answer it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are importing a module yourself with `include` then you need to tell julia that you want to use `t1` from that module by prefixing it with `testie.t1`

Try this

```
if nprocs()<2
  addprocs(1)
end
@everywhere include("testie.jl")
println(remotecall_fetch(testie.t1,2)) #NB prefix here
```

where `testie.jl` is:

```
module testie
export t1
  function t1()
    a= rand()
    println("a is $a, thread $(myid())")
    return a
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I'm not sure I entirely understand the reasoning, but for now I know how to do it. So thanks again.

Comment: whenever you use `include()` to load a module, on another worker or not, you then have to explicity tell julia that you want to use a function from that module (which is not the case when using `using`)